# Localizing Autodesk Forge Extension Button

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

How do we localize the custom extension toolbar button's text/tooltip:

```
myAwesomeToolbarButton {
    background-image: url(/img/myAwesomeIcon.png);
    background-size: 24px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
toolbarButtonShowDockingPanel.addClass('myAwesomeToolbarButton');
toolbarButtonShowDockingPanel.setToolTip('My Awesome extension');
```

Answer (score 0):

Forge Viewer is using a self-maintained [i18next.js](https://www.i18next.com/), and we can add extra locale dictionaries like the one below:

```
class MyAwesomeExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {
        //...

        load() {
            const locales = {
                'en': {
                    'My Awesome extension': 'My Awesome extension'
                },
                'zh-HANT': {
                    'My Awesome extension': '我的超讚外掛'
                }
            };
            this.extendLocalization( locales );

            return true;
         }

        //...

        onToolbarCreated(toolbar) {
            toolbarButtonShowDockingPanel.setToolTip(Autodesk.Viewing.i18n.t('My Awesome extension'));
        }
}
```

You can get supported language codes (saying `en` and `zh-HANT` mentioned above) here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language